# How can I add Linux to the new Windows 8 boot manager?

Tags: linux, windows-8, multi-boot, bootloader

Which OSes can be put into the new bootloader that Windows 8 provides?

It seems to be quite pretty and consistent with the rest of the new Windows 8 design, so it would be cool to put Linux (Ubuntu) into it instead of using [GRUB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB) or [BURG](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/BURG). Besides on my personal system, Linux will be put on a hard drive and not the [SSD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-state_drive), so it would be a bit faster.

Comment: Not sure this is even possible. The only thing that *might* work is [NeoGrub](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uUcdO.jpg) (part of [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/)), but I've never tried something like this.

Comment: also important to note that you can't do this on Windows RT.

Comment: How can you even install another OS on RT

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can do the same as you could in Windows 7, although I'm not sure I'd recommend it using the graphical boot menu (reason in the end).

**Some things first:**

The usual setup for people who have dual boot configurations with Linux being one of the OSs that the machine has installed is to have a Linux bootloader by default, and there add an entry for the Windows OS. What that does is to load the Linux bootloader and if you want to load Windows it chainloads into the Windows bootloader which then boots Windows.

Since usually there's only one Windows installed the menu selector of the Windows bootloader never appears giving the impression that the entry you added in the Linux bootloader actually loads Windows.

The opposite is possible too, although not common among Linux users. For instance, my main bootloader is the one from Windows which then chainloads into a Linux one to boot Linux; I have configured the Linux one to be mostly invisible and load right away though.

**How to add a Linux entry in the Windows bootloader:**

It really depends on what you install first and what later, I'm sure there are some guides around the internet to explain a detailed procedure on how to setup a dual+ boot environment. So I'll just go through 2 different setups:

**When you install Windows first:** In this case when you're installing your Linux distribution, if it allows you to install the bootloader in a partition directly instead of in the MBR of the hard drive do so. After restart you'll find that you're booting Windows just like Linux was not installed at all, after that follow the scenario in which Linux was installed first described below.

If you can only install the bootloader in the MBR of the hard drive after the reboot you'll see a Linux bootloader (Syslinux, GRUB, you name it), choose the Windows entry there and boot into Windows.

Now, I like to use [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) (free for personal usage) to deal with the Windows bootloader, but anything that I do with it can also be accomplished with the proper `bcdboot`, `bcdedit`, etc. commands.

1. Open EasyBCD and go to the "Add New Entry" section and the "Linux/BSD" tab.
2. Select the bootloader you have for your Linux distribution. In case of GRUB2 there's an autoselect mode which will select the appropriate partition for you, for Syslinux for example you have to compulsory select the partition where it is installed.
3. Name the entry, the name you put there is the one that will appear in the Windows bootloader.
4. Select the partition where your bootloader resides or autoselect if that option is possible. In the end you should end up with something like this:

   [image: Adding an entry for a Syslinux loader]
5. Click in "Add entry" and you'll receive the result in the bottom left part of the program:

   [image: Confirmation]
6. Now you have to restore the Windows bootloader as the default one, for that go to the "BCD Deployment" section, there select to write the Vista/7 bootloader in the MBR (which by the way is the same as for Windows 8):

   [image: Writing the new MBR]
7. After that you're all set, you'll receive a similar confirmation as before. When booting up you'll see the boot menu prompting you to select one of them:

   [image: Boot menu example]

**When you install Linux first:** In this case you don't have to restore the MBR (Master Boot Record, tells what to execute next grosso modo) as Windows installation will overwrite any previous value there.

*NOTE: with UEFI and GPT disks this may be different though, but I have no way of trying it out.*

---

**Why I'm not sure I'd recommend doing this using the new graphical boot menu in Windows 8:**

Essentially because the way it works is different than with the textual menu (default for Windows 7). In Windows 7 (or Vista) you're first presented with the boot menu and then it starts to load whatever you choose to, in the new graphical menu it first loads some stuff (= takes time) and then presents you with the boot menu. If you don't select to load Windows 8, it reboots the machine and starts to load whatever you selected which in this case is the Linux bootloader.

I find waiting to load some stuff just to discard it and reboot unnecessary if I just want to boot another OS; but it's my personal opinion on the matter, there's no problem whatsoever by loading Linux, or any other OS in this manner.

Anyway, there are different ways to use the textual boot menu instead in Windows 8, if you're interested check [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/504198/18050) out.

Comment: regarding your recommendation: But it *should* be **only a time-issue**, right? Because that wouldn't be so hard for me personally, since windows is the default OS 95% of the time for me (one could question my sanity for still wanting to Dual-Boot)

Comment: Yes, only timing. I just wouldn't like to wait so much (depends on the PC though) just to select to boot other OSs given that a Linux bootloader is quicker to show up and some of them are graphical too. I will edit the answer to clarify that in case somebody thinks there's some kind of problem by doing that.

Comment: This doesn't work on my UEFI/GPT system.  EasyBCD tries to add .mbr style entries to the BCD instead of .efi entries, and Windows Boot Manager doesn't like them.

Comment: @david25272 Have you tried that again since? Perhaps with a newer version of EasyBCD? That sounds to me like the the author of that utility needs to modify it to make it compatible with UEFI systems and GPT disks.

Comment: @klyonrad No, it's not only a waste of user's time. It is also a hell of a nuisance! Why? Because! It requires the user to attend (baby sit) the computer while it's booting up, and also during any planned or unexpected reboots. It makes remote booting impractical (nearly all multi boot configurations do). It's a waste of people's time and energy, it's annoying, it's impractical, and it's down right stupid. How can Linux have a graphical boot menu, and still boot right up without a reboot, but not Windows? Why load something only to discard it moments later?

Comment: @klyonrad Microsoft knows that this is not an ideal design, but they won't fix it, not even in Windows 10... the all new Windows of Windows... because in their own simple mind there is nothing to fix. They are of course assuming we will all be booting only one single OS, namely Windows, and the latest and greatest version of that OS too.

Comment: @klyonrad Either that, or we will have to learn to put up with this nuisance and waste of time. Only because Microsoft decided to implement some graphical flare to the boot menu in Windows 8, but they didn't know how to design it so it boots the selected OS right away. So they accepted it for what it is... a work in progress! Presented to us as a finished product, of course. They should have consulted the guys behind the many Linux bootloader projects on this. Microsoft software engineers obviously didn't know how to do it themselves.

Comment: Actually you don't have to load "Meto Boot Manager" (which takes very long to load). In EasyBCD you can tick option to boot into textual menu. This way it loads faster and choosing Linux OS will directly forward you to GRUB (computer don't restart). So basically there is no downside using this option (only it's uglier than metro)

Comment: Windows bootloader != Windows Boot Manager