# Every windows 8 boot breaks grub

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, boot, grub, uefi

I have Windows 8 and Ubuntu 13.04 dual booting with UEFI and grub. (re-used the windows UEFI partition)
After I used boot-repair, everything seemed fine.
After I boot into Windows, however, I can't boot into Ubuntu anymore. Grub still allows me to select it, but the screen just goes blank and there are no error messages.

Here's the really weird part: If I have the liveUSB stick plugged in (but not being booted from), then Ubuntu boots. And after Ubuntu boots, I can remove the live USB stick and continue to boot normally into Ubuntu... until I boot into Windows 8. Then I need to have the live USB key to "unlock" the ability to boot into linux again.

I've heard of Dell's software writing to the EFI partition, but this is an Asus machine and I haven't heard of their shovelware doing that.

Comment: How do you know it's the Windows boot that's breaking GRUB? Does restarting from Linux back into Linux work fine without a USB?

Comment: Yes, Mehrdad. Rebooting from linux to linux has no problems whatsoever. And booting from linux to windows has no problems. But once I boot into windows, I cannot boot into linux unless I have the key plugged in.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by you "re-used the windows UEFI partition" for Linux?

Comment: With other installs, I've set up a separate partition to install Grub on, and had the BIOS load it instead of the windows EFI partition. But in this case (due to a few laptop-related reasons), I installed grub in the existing EFI partition. I'd be fine with using a modified Windows bootloader, but EasyBCD won't install on the EFI partition unless it's marked as primary, and I don't think Windows 8 disk manager  would let me modify the flags.

Comment: I experience a very similar dual-boot hell on a Sony Vaio laptop which I reported here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/efibootmgr/+bug/1314759 . Are the symptoms that I describe there similar to what you're seeing on your Asus machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the answer might be in [this other post](https://superuser.com/questions/499923/preinstalled-windows-8-and-linux-uefi-dual-boot-on-a-laptop/528581): run the following in Windows 8 to prevent corruption on shutdown:

```
powercfg /h off
```

Unfortunately, I can't test it because EasyBCD broke the Windows bootloader, then EasyRE failed to repair Win8 but disabled my ability to boot linux. The break was so bad that Windows recovery drive can't do anything either. So thanks to neosmart, I went from a small problem with two OS's, to a machine that's less useful than a potato.

Rather than try to dig my way out of this mess, I think I'm just going to wipe the system and start from scratch. If it is applicable, I'll try the above command and report back.

Comment: You're just switching off hibernation and Fast Startup here.

Comment: I haven't been able to try it yet because the other tools have destroyed any chances of recovery.
But it seems as though that's a plausible solution if the problem really is how Windows 8 does a suspend-to-disk upon shutdown, which can cause corruption to mounted volumes when booting linux after.

Comment: Just do a restart. Restart never saves anything.

Comment: So for every time I boot into Windows, I'd have to restart into linux to shut down, just to keep the "fast startup" option?

Seems like I'd lose any time savings while also losing the ability to do an unattended shutdown.

If it does prevent the problems I was talking about, I'd rather disable fast startup.

Comment: Sorry, do this. From a command prompt in Windows, do `shutdown /t 0`. This is without hybrid shutdown. This should work. Normal shutdown is `shutdown /t /h 0`

Answer (score 0):

Your linux boot loader has been installed on the USB stick. Manually you can add entries to GRUB2 using a software known as EasyBCD or Win2grub.

Comment: But if that were the case, why wouldn't I need the USB stick for every boot? It only assists when booting the first time after a Windows boot. After that, booting to Linux is just fine. (Not saying you're incorrect, just wondering out loud). Going to try your suggestion.

Comment: Unfortunately, EasyBCD is a tool for modifying the Windows Bootloader, not modifying Grub2. I also can't find the Win2grub tool you mentioned; Google links back to your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a side effect from Microsoft requiring boot-loaders be signed, does Ubuntu 13.04 have a signed bootloader?

Comment: According to the BIOS, Secure Boot State and Secure Boot Control are disabled. I'm not sure if I have to check anywhere else though.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that, that's probably not the issue then man. :/