# GRUB disappears when i turn off computer

Tags: grub, kali-linux

I enter with a live CD, then I reinstall the GRUB. All works fine. After a reboot, GRUB is still there. But if I turn off the computer and then start it again, GRUB is not there anymore. I have to reinstall it to boot my Kali Linux.

What I have to do to keep my GRUB?

Comment: Are you using uefo or mbr booting? Do you have the boot flag toggled on for the boot partition, and where os grub installed (also, have you tried upgrading your BIOS?)

Comment: mbr. The problem appeared after windows update. I updated bios 1 month ago.

Comment: Did you reinstall grub to the mbr (ie /dev/sdX) or the partition (/dev/sdX1).  If the latter, try the former. Also ensure the boot flag is toggled on on the partition which holds /boot

Answer (score 0):

Windows, especially newer versions, like(s) overwriting foreign OSes bootloaders. For EFI, this is not a big problem, as there can be different bootloaders. But for BIOS / legacy boot, there can be one bootloader only.

The safest solution is switching to EFI boot or purging the Windows installation / not starting it at all.

**EDIT:** According to [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/499923/preinstalled), it could help to disable hibernation on Windows:

```
powercfg /h off
```

Comment: i changed to EFI...same problem

Comment: Does the bootloader work multiple times when starting Linux only?

Comment: yes...if i enter windows then restart grub is not there anymore

Comment: You could try to disable hibernation (see above)