# How to add Ubuntu image to Windows 8 boot menu

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8

Is it possible to add an image to the Windows 8 boot menu for Linux/Ubuntu?

[How can I add Linux to the new Windows 8 boot manager?](https://superuser.com/questions/499617/how-can-i-add-linux-to-the-new-windows-8-boot-manager)

Comment: The linked question contains instructions on how to do it.  The process is no different.  You install the operating system then modify Grub, this process, is well documented.  I count 5 related questions all with answers.

Comment: Do you mean *picture*, like Ubuntu logo or something?

Answer (score 0):

If by "ubuntu image" you mean a Ubuntu .iso image, you can simply follow the EasyBCD tutorial from the link you provided, but instead of selecting the partition where your bootloader resides, you can browse to and select ubuntu .iso file on your hard drive.