# How to restore Windows bootloader and still have Kali Linux

Tags: windows-8.1, grub, bootloader, kali-linux

I installed Kali Linux 1.0.9a on my Windows 8.1 system today and installed it, but I don't want the GRUB bootloader menu. I want to use the original Windows bootloader. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done this before, same OS same conditions. Note that if you want to use the Win8 bootloader, if you were to choose to boot into Kali, your computer will restart a second time since Win8 'preloads' some system files which gives you the impression that it loads extremely fast.

**EDIT: IMPORTANT**

This applies if **GRUB is currently your bootloader**. If the Windows bootloader is already default, you won't be able to boot into Kali, then follow the steps below but **skip step 7**. This is because if you do step 7 you are essentially writing the Windows bootloader (since it is already default) and you will not be able to boot into Kali. Also make a Win8 repair disc/USB first to be safe, and backup your files as always!

1. Boot into Windows and install [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/).
2. Open **EasyBCD** and go to the **"Add New Entry"** section and the **"Linux/BSD"** tab.
3. Select the bootloader you have for your Kali - for GRUB2 there's an autoselect mode which will select the appropriate partition for you.
4. Name the entry, eg "Kali Linux". The name you put there is the one that will appear in the Windows bootloader.
5. Select the partition where Kali's bootloader is, autoselect if possible. Now it should look like this (apart from the Kali name etc):
   [image]
6. Click in "Add entry" and you'll receive the result in the bottom left part of the program (different name):
   [image]
7. Now you have to restore the Windows bootloader as the default one, for that go to the "BCD Deployment" section, there select to write the Vista/7 bootloader in the MBR (which by the way is the same as for Windows 8):
   [image]
8. Restart Windows if you want to and you’ll see a Windows boot menu rather than the Linux one. However, you will find that the menu is text-based; but you can easily switch to a more graphical version.
9. To use the beautiful Windows 8.1 bootloader open an elevated Command Prompt and type `bcdboot C:\Windows`, press Enter (wait till cmd acknowledges it) and restart Windows and you should see a far friendlier menu from which to choose your operating system!

[image]

Note that sometimes after a few reboots you'll end up booting into the traditional Windows bootloader again, I'm not sure why, but just repeat **step 9** and it will be fixed.

Upon choosing Kali, you will be directed to GRUB again. If you want to boot directly into Kali, you might want to [set GRUB timeout to zero](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148095/how-do-i-set-the-grub-timeout-and-the-grub-default-boot-entry).

**PROBLEMS YOU MAY RUN INTO**

**1. "Missing Operating System" upon reboot**

This may happen if you accidentally delete the Windows entry in EasyBCD. Just boot up using the repair disc created earlier and enter **Command Prompt** via Advanced Startup Options/System Recovery Options. **Rebuild the BCD** by following the instructions [here](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fixtheproblem/ht/rebuild-bcd-store-windows.htm). Upon reboot you will get the traditional Windows bootloader so you may have to redo the steps above.

[Similar superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/499617/how-can-i-add-linux-to-the-new-windows-8-boot-manager). I initially followed the instructions here but it didn't work for me because the answer didn't have step 9, which I found - after much searching -  [here.](http://www.maketecheasier.com/configure-the-boot-menu-windows-8/)

Comment: Is Kali Linux GRUB2?

Comment: It should be, to check just boot into GRUB(2) and there should be the version on top. GRUB 2 is version 1.98 or later. What version is your Kali?

Comment: 1.98 (or 99). But I thought anything below 2 was legacy. Thanks.

Comment: GRUB 1.98 is GRUB 2. I think GRUB1 (legacy GRUB) never got beyond about 0.97.

Comment: I tried bcdboot C:\Windows but it said failure when attempting to copy files. I'm using a admin command prompt.

Comment: Is your computer UEFI? Did you click the Write MBR in EasyBCD? See http://diggerpage.blogspot.co.nz/2014/04/bcdboot-failure-when-attempting-to-copy.html

Comment: Also see here: http://www.howtogeek.com/forum/topic/failure-attempting-to-copy-boot-files Apparently the command differs for different OSs.

Comment: Haha congratulations :) I'm dualbooting it right now actually :D

Comment: I had to install Ubuntu 14.10 because I tried that, and my MBR was screwed up. It just said "Missing Operating System". Now I have to use GRUB but I'm going to try adding an OS with EasyBCD and see if I still have the Windows 8.1 boot menu.

Comment: I ran into this problem before, did you accidentally delete the Windows entry or something in EasyBCD? You just need to use the Win8 startup repair disc/USB and rebuild the BCD in Command Prompt by following the instructions here. http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fixtheproblem/ht/rebuild-bcd-store-windows.htm  Also is your computer UEFI or BIOS? x64 or 32bit? I dual-booted Kali and Win8.1 yesterday and it all worked fine for me, only difference was the EDIT I made in the answer.

Comment: My bios type is Legacy (maybe because I upgraded from Windows Vista) and my pc is x32.

Comment: @kprovost7314 OK, mine is same but x64. Does it work now? I finished dual-booting yesterday and now it works, but I installed 1.09 instead of 1.09a.

Comment: > Step 1: Boot into windows.

And how do I do that if I don't have a windows bootloader??