# Does msconfig's boot setting show for Windows Bootloader entries?

Tags: windows, windows-8, boot, grub, bootloader

I noticed on msconfig a boot tab. Currently, it has just one entry--Windows 8.1. If I were to dual boot Ubuntu into the computer, and use Windows Bootloader as my bootloader instead of GRUB, using [this](https://superuser.com/questions/831699/how-to-restore-windows-bootloader-and-still-have-kali-linux/834559#834559) method, would another entry appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you will have an entry about Ubuntu operating system information similar to Windows 8.1