# Windows 8.1 EFI Graphical Bootloader: Change OS Thumbnails

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, multi-boot, bootloader, efi

I've just used EasyBCD to tweak my Windows 8.1 EFI graphical bootloader, adding entries for Windows XP and Ubuntu. Both of them have a boring thumbnail of a window, while Windows 8 has a thumbnail of its logo as shown in this picture:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4ZZN.png]

It's purely a cosmetic wish, but is it possible to change the thumbnails for the other two entries?

Comment: can you please post a picture of your issue? I currently don't really understand it.

Comment: Here's a [picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/t4ZZN.png) I grabbed off a related [Superuser post](http://superuser.com/a/499652/404054)

Comment: I have no idea if this is possible.

Comment: I don't know if this is possible. But instead if you're happy to use another boot manager, then try [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/). rEFInd is very nicely "themeable".

Comment: Sweet, I gotta look into that ^-^