# Windows 8.1 using Win7 style bootloader after boot entry change in EasyBCD

Tags: windows-8, multi-boot, bootloader, bcd

I recently installed Xubuntu in a dual-boot environment with Windows 8.1. Following [this guide](https://superuser.com/questions/499617/how-can-i-add-linux-to-the-new-windows-8-boot-manager) I was able to use the Windows 8 bootloader instead of GRUB to boot into Xubuntu.

However, recently I converted my Xubuntu install to Ubuntu using [this guide](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntucat/tag/pure-ubuntu/). This worked and I was able to use the Ubuntu environment instead of Xubuntu. But this meant a problem. Although the installation was now a Ubuntu one, the Windows bootloader still listed it as Xubuntu. Thinking this would be an easy fix, I loaded up EasyBCD and changed the name of the entry to Ubuntu like so:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/T4Bxu77.png]

And that's when the problem started.

Now, when I boot up my computer, instead of the snazzy Windows 8 bootloader, I get the old textual Windows 7 style bootloader. The entries are there and it works, however I would much rather use the Windows 8 bootloader. However, I cannot get it to come back. I've tried:

- Rewriting the bootloader in EasyBCD (Multiple times)
- Removing the Ubuntu entry and then adding it again
- Removing the Ubuntu entry and rebooting (did nothing at all, gave me the same menu)
- Changing `bootmenupolicy` from standard to legacy and back again.

How can I get the Windows 8 bootloader back (Preferably with EasyBCD and not a repair disc)? I should mention that my computer does not support UEFI, so any complications that might arise from an EFI BIOS are not a problem. Everything is legacy.

EDIT:

As requested, here is the results of `bcdedit /enum`. I should note that my Windows installation is on the F: Drive.

```
Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume1
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-GB
inherit                 {globalsettings}
integrityservices       Enable
default                 {current}
resumeobject            {0ac2e94d-9111-11e4-a30b-aa4ab5087796}
displayorder            {current}
                        {15842726-9264-11e4-8259-74de2b71de90}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 300
displaybootmenu         Yes

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {current}
device                  partition=F:
path                    \WINDOWS\system32\winload.exe
description             Windows 8.1
locale                  en-GB
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {7b41b78a-376d-11e3-9691-b8dc54503be8}
integrityservices       Enable
recoveryenabled         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=F:
systemroot              \WINDOWS
resumeobject            {0ac2e94d-9111-11e4-a30b-aa4ab5087796}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard

Real-mode Boot Sector
---------------------
identifier              {15842726-9264-11e4-8259-74de2b71de90}
device                  partition=F:
path                    \NST\AutoNeoGrub1.mbr
description             Ubuntu
```

Comment: That’s still the Windows 8 bootloader. The (blue-ish) screen you’re probably expecting only appears after Windows has booted almost completely. While maybe not as stylish, the current situation is much better.

Comment: @Daniel B Okay. I realize that the Modern bootloader is less practical, however I much prefer using it (I don't know, personal taste). I'd rather get back the Modern bootloader. How? I thought about rewriting GRUB2, and then following the guide linked again.

Comment: Could you please add the output of `bcdedit /enum` to your question? You need to execute this command as admin.

Comment: @DanielB I've added the information from `bcdedit`.

Comment: Well, I guess it’s not the easy solution then (about `bootmenupolicy`). You’ll have to wait until someone has another idea, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This used to work for me:

1. Open **EasyBCD** in Windows 8.1, click **Write MBR** (with *Install the Win7...to the MBR* checked), OK and close.
2. Open an elevated Command Prompt and type `bcdboot C:\Windows`, press Enter (and wait till cmd acknowledges it).
3. Reboot (maybe twice, try once first).

Check if the Win8 bootloader is used.

Sometimes when I boot into Ubuntu and back to Windows it reverts to the Win7 bootloader, then I have to redo the process. Sometimes if I leave it as it is, it just uses the Win8 bootloader again!

Perhaps someone else could explain this phenomenon.

Comment: Will I need to add the Ubuntu entry again?

Answer (score -1):

The correct solution in this case would be to delete element "displaybootmenu" which causes old text style boot menu.

Can be achieved easily with [Visual BCD Editor](http://www.boyans.net).

Using "bcdboot" in this case removes the connection with recovery - "Repair your computer" disappears from advanced boot menu.

Comment: For the down voters "bcdboot" in this case is like shooting birds with a cannon ;))