# Can't install grub on MBR, encountered an error "Unable to install GRUB in /dev/sda"

Tags: linux, partitioning, grub, mbr, linux-distributions

I want to install a linux distribution on my computer. I have a SSD and an HDD. The SSD has Windows 8.1 and I partitioned 200 gigs from my 1 TB HDD to install linux. The linux installation was going smoothly until it reached the step where it needed to install Grub. I encountered the error "Unable to install GRUB in /dev/sda"

The Linux partition is in the drive /dev/sdb and my Windows is on /dev/sda. I read online that since I'm putting linux on a seperate drive from my Windows that I need to install Grub on the MBR which means that I need to install Grub in /dev/sda, right?

Also, I want to mention that fast boot and secure boot are disabled.

I need some advice, I've been working on this for hours!

Comment: GRUB does not need to be on /dev/sda.  You might want to add the information from the comments on Mario's answer to your question so all of the diagnostic information is in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you install GRUB on another partition (i.e. the linux partition?).

If so, you could then just [add GRUB to Windows' bootloader as described in the answer to this more or less related quesiton](https://superuser.com/questions/499617/how-can-i-add-linux-to-the-new-windows-8-boot-manager).

Comment: Yeah I can install grub on the actual partition, which in my case would be /dev/sdb4, and the installation goes by fine when doing it like that, but when I reboot the grub menu doesn't show up

Comment: @DsDude You'll have to tell Windows' bootloader that there's some other OS there. See the question/answer I linked. It includes step-by-step procedure on how you're able to essentially add GRUB to the Windows bootloader.

Comment: It didn't work, I installed grub in /dev/sdb4 and used EasyBCD to to add the entry of partition 4 of my second hard driveand I also wrote to the MBR, but when my computer boots up and gives me the choice to pick between windows and linux I choose linux but it fails to start up

Comment: @DsDude Any error message? Maybe update your initial question with what you've tried now and the results.