# VMDK linux physical partition + windows

Tags: linux, vmware, windows-10

so since i just found out you can point a vmdk to a physical partition and virtualize, I want to try experimenting.

**The Plan:**

- Windows 10 OS on own drive
- linux (likely ubuntu or mint) partition on secondary drive
- point vmdk to linux to load in virtual box on windows
- add linux to bcd to allow for real boot if necesary

**The Setup:**

```
Disk 0================= SSD 60GB
| windows OS           |
=======================

Disk 1========================================== HDD 500GB
| data storage                      | linux     |
================================================
```

**Concerns:**

- Is partition format important? (i.e. does virt from windows require
  NTFS?)
- adding linux to win 10 bcd?? ([this way](https://superuser.com/questions/499617/how-can-i-add-linux-to-the-new-windows-8-boot-manager)??)
- I get the feeling I cant just point to a linux install and boot. I would prefer not use GRUB or any second bootloader, but I'm unsure the complications of this with virtual. (`ubiquity --no-bootloader` ok?)

I realize other people have posted similar scenarios, but there is little info on bootloader/multiple drives.