# Can't extend volume in Windows after deleting Ubuntu dual boot, and Ubuntu still shows up in boot options?

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, boot, partitioning

I installed Ubuntu to my second SSD (500 GB not main) as dual boot. I have now deleted it as I don't need it but whenever I try to extend the volume to the unallocated space it says there isn't enough disk space. Moreover, I still get the option to boot into Ubuntu even after deleting it. I tried following this tutorial https://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader to delete the ubuntu bootloader but when I went into the EFI partition there was no Ubuntu to remove. I'm really confused right now. I've attached a picture below to show my drive state for clarity. Please do  help if you can. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: You have two ESPs (EFI System Partition), one per drive. Although admissible that's strongly advised against unless for special usages and when users know what they're doing and why. The problem now is you don't know which is which so better leave it alone. You DON'T need to dlete the Ubuntu entry file, just set your firmware (UEFI) to boot Windows directly. The end result is exactly the same so don't bother. Now, re: the question about extending a partition you should be aware there's precisely one ESP on the way and if that one is the one being used then moving it may make it unbootable.

Answer (score 0):

You can reinstall the Windows boot manager by booting off Windows bootable media.  Press `F8` while booting for Windows Recovery Menu.

- Click on Troubleshoot.
- Click on Advanced options to get into Automatic Repair menu.
- Click Startup Repair.

---

I ran [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=fix%20ubuntu%20windows%20boot%20menu%20not%20loading%20windows) google search.

**People also ask #2:**
How to fix Windows Boot Manager from Ubuntu?
You can reinstall the Windows boot manager by booting off Windows bootable media.

Press F8 while booting the system to go into the Windows Recovery Menu.

- Click on Troubleshoot.
- Click on Advanced options to get into Automatic Repair menu.
- Click Startup Repair.

Feb 11, 2018
[How to recover the Windows 10 MBR after w Linux install?](https://superuser.com/questions/1294071/how-to-recover-the-windows-10-mbr-after-w-linux-install)

Answer (score 0):

> I try to extend the volume to the unallocated space it says there isn't enough disk space.

This is not a precise description!

Extending the partion Data (E:) on disk 0 will fail as the 513 MB EFI partition prevents it. You will either have to move the EFI partition towards the end of the disk to create free space directly after partition E:. Otherwise you can delete the EFI partition on disk 0 if it is not in use.

Answer (score -1):

You have to reinstall the Windows' bootloader and use a kind of partition manager to extend the main partition. [The one I used years ago](https://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html), you can use it to modify the partition even when the file system is mounted.