# Is it possible to native boot a vhdx after dual booting linux?

Tags: linux, windows-10, uefi, bootloader

I want to install linux on a separate nvme and still boot natively to vhdx's that I will add to the windows boot manager with one normal windows on a separate nvme. Is this possible or does grub completely replace the windows boot manager altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is certainly possible, I do it.

Grub doesn't replace the Windows boot loader - it (generally) calls it.  See the [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#Windows_installed_in_UEFI/GPT_mode) for details.

Alternatively you can add a call to Linux from Windows boot loader (see [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/499617/how-can-i-add-linux-to-the-new-windows-8-boot-manager)) or, probably the simplest way, call either Grub or Windows from EFI either direct from your EFI menu at startup or using a boot manager such as [rEFInd](https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/).

Note I assume you have UEFI system as you have nvme but the same idea applies to legacy boot.